# Modified Newton's method for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, approximation

Let $f \in C^2[a,b]$ so that $f'(x) >0$ for every $ x\in [a,b]$.  Solve the equation $f(x) = 0$  by applying Newton's method to the function :
$$g(x) =\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{f'(x)}}$$
Write the Newtion iteration of g and determine the iteration sequence for $f(x) = x^2-2$ and it's order of convergence.

I started solving this by writing:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{\sqrt{f'(x_n)}} \frac{2f'(x_n)^{3/2}}{2f'(x_n)^2 - f(x_n)f''(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{2f(x_n)f'(x_n)}{2f'(x_n)^2 - f(x_n)f''(x_n)} $$

If that's ok I have $f(x) = x^2-2%$ and : $f'(x) = 2x$, $f''(x) = 2$, $f'(x)^2 = 4x^2$.

If I plug the values into the relation I wrote above and try to iterate to find the solution $\sqrt{2}$ I get wrong values and that mean I am doing something wrong here. Also how to approach finding the order of converfence for this sequence?

Comment: Shouldn't you have gotten $$\dfrac{g(x)}{g'(x)} = \dfrac{2 f(x) f'(x)}{2 f'(x)^2-f(x) f''(x)}$$

Comment: This is one approach to compactly remember Halley's method. The idea is that the fraction removes the curvature at the root so that $g$ is more linear at the root than $f$.

Comment: I edited the result, it was my bad!

Comment: now if I plug in the values I get $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2-2}{\frac{3}{2}x_{n} + 1}$ which converges to the solution

Comment: You have $2 -...$ in the denominator, is that correct or a typo?

Comment: Definetly a typo, haven't written in a long time on this

Comment: I just plugged in for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$

Comment: I divided the entire relation you wrote by $4x$